# How to make entity autoupdate after exceeded certain date?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I working on app which sets tasks for employee. The task will expire after specyfic date. Task has boolean field "isArchived". I don't know how to make it by change that field automatically after exceed "expire date". Does anyone know how solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
Create an @Scheduled task that pulls tasks that have an expiry date < now.

Comment: But I don't want to delete whole task but change its field "isarchieved" from "false" to "true" after permament date.